# Can I manually add an "Email" activity in the GUI without sending it?

Tags: email, activities

To keep track of communications with contacts, CiviCRM has *Activities* e.g. documenting e-mail conversations. In the `Activities` tab of a contact I can create these from the `New activity` dropdown.

This provides the option `Send an Email`. However, using that I can only make CiviCRM actually send out an email to the contact. We usually send emails from a normal mail client instead.

What I am looking for is a possibility to add an `Email` activity to a contact without actually sending out a mail. (To document an email that has already been sent from outside CiviCRM)

Currently we use a workaround: A custom activity type *documented Email*. But it would avoid confusion, if all mail would be of the same activity type *Email* regardless of how it was send out.

Is there a way for this in Civi or an extension?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the inbound email processor script. You can forward and/or cc a mailbox, and civi can read from the mailbox and attach it to the relevant contacts.

Details are here:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Autofiling+email+activities+via+EmailProcessor

Answer (score 2):

We brought templates/CRM/Activity/Form/ActivityLinks.tpl into the custom templates folder and added some jQuery to it to *hide* certain custom activity types of our own making from being manually created by staff. If you're going for the code route, that and its corresponding PHP class is probably a good place to look.

Alternatively, compare the URL for writing an email:

```
https://ffnew/civicrm/activity/email/add?action=add&reset=1&cid=90948&selectedChild=activity&atype=3
```

and for adding a different activity type:

```
https://ffnew/civicrm/activity/add?action=add&reset=1&cid=90948&selectedChild=activity&atype=64
```

Start by clicking 'Send an Email', then take the 'email/' out of the URL. Does that give you what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

One option if you are using Drupal as your CMS is to set up a webform for creating email activities. The webform can create the activity for you without sending the email.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the System Setting (menu Administer/System Setting/Outbound Email) to 'redirect to database' you can create an Email activity but it will not be sent.

Comment: This wouldn't help if you wanted to be able to both send emails and log emails that had been sent via another system though.