# Can webform-civicrm cause an Activity of type Email to actually send the email from CiviCRM

Tags: webform-civicrm, activities, email

Scenario is users who are not accessing civi but are doing it all via Views and Webforms.

I created a webform

- contact 1 is logged in user
- contact 2 is 'target'
- Activity is of type Email

Outcome I want is that civi actually sends the email.

My testing shows this does not happen. If i 'assign' the ticket to someone else (or eg the Sender) then a 'you have been assigned' does get sent.

Is this meant to not be possible? Or is it a missing feature?

Note: seems like the reverse of [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2521/can-i-manually-add-an-email-activity-in-the-gui-without-sending-it) where coleman explains that 'not' sending the email is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really the opposite of the answer I gave in the [other question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2521/can-i-manually-add-an-email-activity-in-the-gui-without-sending-it). The webform-civicrm module does not treat the "send email" activity type as special. Just like the "print pdf" activity type, it dutifully creates the activity, but does not do any extra civi-workflow stuff with it. To actually send an email, I suggest doing this via the webform.

Comment: Ok - so for sending from webform I think it makes sense to have 'display name' for cid1 for the 'from name'. currently not available is it? any suggested easy workarounds?

Comment: The "existing contact" should show up as display name. Actually you might need this patch: https://www.drupal.org/node/2672482

Comment: thought i would have a go at reviewing your patch. Outcome was that with From it changed from eg 103 to Peter DavisFZ - so i guess that confirms that yes I needed your patch and that your patch is gooood

Comment: Coleman - is webform adding the Activity via the API and hence would https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.emailapi fill the gap in doing this directly with civicrm?

Comment: Looks like that extension would add an api which _could_ be called by webform_civicrm when saving the activity. I don't think installing the extension would do anything on its own.